# Massive Loss of reputation overnight

Tags: support

Yesterday I was on 145 reputation when finished work for the day, I come back in today log in and I now only have 20. Why is this?

Comment: thats not really anything to do with me though, seems a bit unfair to punish me for it

Comment: Yeah, we'll let the moderators be the judge of that one. Letting you keep the reputation you've gained because someone likes you is unfair to the community at large, which is why it's reversed. Bear in mind that it works both ways - if you had been serially downvoted, that would also have been corrected.

Answer (score 11):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6139904/pineapplelord?tab=reputation&sort=time

> -125  5 hours ago reversal    Voting corrected ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed))